# I get this message'rule useless in grammar'

Tags: bison

I'm new to Bison. I wrote some rules but I get a lot of 'rule useless in grammar'.

I think 'expr' cause this problem. Please help me.

[image: image of result]

```
File : 
| class {printf("accepted");}
; 
class : CLASS IDENT '{' function  '}'
| CLASS IDENT '{'  global '}'
;
global : data_type IDENT 
;
function : 
|data_type IDENT'('Params')' '{'statement'}'
|VOID IDENT'('Params')' '{'statement'}'
;
Params : data_type IDENT 
| data_type IDENT',' Params
;
data_type : INT_T 
|DOUBLE_T
|BOOL_T 
|VOID;
;       
statement : WHILE '(' expr')'  statement  
| FOR'('data_type IDENT '=' expr ';' expr ';' expr')'  statement 
;   
expr:   expr COMP expr
|expr '=' expr
|INT_T
|BOOL_T     
;
```

Comment: There is a doubled semicolon here: `|VOID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `statement` has only recursive rules. That makes `statement` impossible to use in a derivation because any derivation starting with `statement` never terminates.

Because `statement` cannot be used to parse any finite string, bison removes it and all its rules from the grammar, as well as any rules which use `statement`. With those rules removed, `expr` and `Params` are no longer referred to in the grammar, so they are also marked useless.

You probably intended `statement` to have other, non-recursive alternatives, such as `expr`.

Comment: "I added the expr to the statement ... so much better but I got the error:conflicts: 5 shift/reduce" ...Thanks anyway. Maybe I should take a closer look at the code again

Comment: @yhab: there are other problems with your grammar. If you don't define precedence levels, you'll get lots of conflicts, for example. I addressed the one you asked about. There are some good resources for learning bison; you could start by studying the examples in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples). For a gentler introduction, find a copy of John Levine's book (published by Safari).